# How to connect an old dumb terminal to a modern PC?

Tags: terminal, vi

Could one connect an old dumb terminal to a modern PC?  I have this fantasy of hacking around with some vi on an old ADM-3A, but have no idea if it's networkable with modern hardware.

Comment: They can treat masochism now....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably need a serial-to-USB adapter.  Otherwise, and assuming you set `$TERM` properly, it should just work.